# Background Julia TCP server

Tags: unix, tcp, julia

**My use case**

Create a Julia background process which I can call from another server. When I pass it some arguments, it does stuff, sends a response, then waits for the next request.

**What I tried**

If there's a more 'Julia' way of doing it, let me know, but I thought this would be a good use case for a TCP server like in the docs' example:

```
using Sockets

@async begin
       server = listen(2001)
       while true
           sock = accept(server)
           @async while isopen(sock)
               write(sock,readline(sock))
           end
       end
   end
```

...Which works fine in the REPL! but I want it to run in the background permanently so I don't need to keep a REPL open.

When I put the above in app.jl and run `julia app.jl` it obviously runs then quits instantly. What's the best way to keep it running, even after closing my terminal?

**Edits**

- My client is an Elixir server.
- I would prefer TCP over HTTP just for performance reasons, but I can be persuaded if it ends up being too much work.

Comment: How do you want to call that process? What is your client? If your client is Julia for some scenarios the simplest approach is to use `Distributed` for calling remote Julia and than not to worry about anything. Or do you need it to be a socket server? Here you can either implement like you tried or use `JuliaWebAPI` and `ZeroMQ` to publish Julia function as RESTful service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put several option in the comment.
Now the simplest approach is to remove `@async` in front of the `begin` statement in your code and run (I assume Linux):

```
nohup julia app.jl &
```

Of course you can add `1>` and `2>` to redirect standard output and standard error, put it as a `cron` job etc.

`JuliaWebAPI` + `ZeroMQ` will be however more robust for production systems and `Distributed` will be more convenient for computational solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for anyone in the future, a better answer (depending on your use case) might be to add this at the bottom of the file:

`Base.JLOptions().isinteractive==0 && wait()`

Which will cause it to not quit automatically. No external libraries or frameworks required.

Comment: There is a function called `isinteractive` that is already exported from Base and returns a boolean, so it can be simplified as `isinteractive() || wait()`

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Much cleaner ^